# Adapted to filtration or adopted to filtration?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

I have seen both statements being used frequently in formal texts (i.e. lecture notes), i.e. **"adopted"** as well as **"adapted**" when referring to a process that is "adapted" to some filtration.

Which one is correct? For years now, I keep thinking that "adopted" is in fact miss-spelling of "adapted", because in the English language, it does not make sense to me to say that a process is "adopted" to filtration (could be "adopted by filtration", but it seems odd to say it is "adopted to filtration").

Are both acceptable?

Comment: Adapted, only.  (If you see adopted in this context it's a typo or a misunderstanding.)